# How to find all documents and populate them in mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, populate

I have two models...User and Pharmacy.
User model has pharmacy property as a reference.
I'm trying to show all users and their properties in one page.

Pharmacy model

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var PharmacySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    province: String,
    followers: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
        },
    ],
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Pharmacy", PharmacySchema);
```

and User model

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    accountFirst: Number,
    accountSecond: Number,
    pharmacy: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Pharmacy",
    },
    date: String,
});



module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

app.js

```
app.get("/pharmacy", async function (req, res) {
    const users = await User.find({}).populate('pharmacy').exec();
    
    res.render("pharmacy", { users });
})
```

pharmacy.ejs

```
<ul>
    <% users.forEach(function(user){ %>
    <li>name: <%=user.name%> Account Number: <%=user.accountFirst%> - <%=user.accountSecond%> pharmacy: <%=user.pharmacy.name%> </li>
    <%})%>
</ul>
```

but I cannot access to <%=user.pharmacy.name%> and got an error

```
TypeError: D:\VS_CODE\mask\views\pharmacy.ejs:5
    3|     <% users.forEach(function(user){ %>
    4|     <li>name: <%=user.name%> Account Number: <%=user.accountFirst%> - <%=user.accountSecond%> pharmacy:
 >> 5|         <%=user.pharmacy.name%> </li>
    6|     <%})%>
    7| </ul>

Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

Comment: I just want to point out that your current EJS template assumes that every user actually has a pharmacy (you'll get null error now if a pharmacy is missing). Also, you actually have to keep the fields synced up manually.  Lets say you have `pharmacy.followers.push(user); pharmacy.save()` then you also need to `user.pharmacy = pharmacy; user.save();` There is no magic that does that for you. Populate simply converts object-ids into their corresponding document.

Comment: I had missing pharmacy field data of some users. After I filled it, it is ok now. Thanks.